# Distribution of dependent variable in linear regression with fixed effect (panel data)

Tags: regression, distributions

I have a question regarding the hypothesis of the distribution of the dependent variable in a linear regression model.

I have a model to assess the earning losses of displaced workers. I have observations of treated (displaced) and control (non displaced) workers. When a worker is displaced and only finds a job years after, **I assign 0 to its earnings on every unemployment year**.I have five cohorts of displaced workers (2002 to 2006), and I assess the impact of displacement on annual earnings from t-2 to t+5 (t being the year of displacement, it varies depending on which cohort the worker belongs). Control workers can become treated afterwards and every worker can be used several times as control (imagine you are a control worker in 2003 and 2004 because you have only been displaced in 2005).

I did a matching between displaced and non displaced worker based on displacement year and several other variables (age, sexe etc) based on the probability of being displaced (propensity score) and obtain a weakly balanced panel data. Then, I use a linear fixed effect regression (xtreg) to assess the effect of treatment on the annual earnings of workers.

The problem is: since I put 0 for earnings for all observations where the worker is unemployed, the distribution of my dependent variable is not continuous (there are a mass of observations where the earnings are equal to 0, and the rest of the distribution is continuous). Nevertheless, there are several paper in the same case using a linear regression anyway.

What do you think ? I would be very glad if someone could help me with that.

Thank you very much !!!!

Eugenie

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking at a hurdle model of some sort. Workers earn $0 unless they break some hurdle of characteristics (job hunting, soft skills, etc.).  After that point they are employed and have earnings greater than 0.

Using a hurdle model will better allow you to estimate the effects of how many people have jobs, and the wages of those jobs when they occur.

Note unemployment might be highly endogenous, those who are low quality workers are probably more likely to be fired, so your estimate of the effect of unemployment on future low wages/unemployment will likely be overestimated.

Many papers use linear regression (Do you mean IV techniques? They're linear but not OLS.) so they can estimate the effect at the mean and don't estimate the intensive and extensive margins.

Suggestion: You might want to ask in the economics forum. Their techniques are going to be better suited for this task than typical ML approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much. To avoid endogeneity, I only include displaced workers following firm closure :such separations are unrelated to the performance and career aspirations of workers and have been considered exogenous from a worker's perspective. I also use matching to enhance the plausibility of this exogeneity assumption. Other papers use diff-in-diff regression with individual FE to assess the effect of displacement on workers. Estimating the effect at mean is not a problem, I only want to know if the method is wrong when the dependent variable is distributed with mass effects on zero.

Comment: You should also look at Tobit for similar cases, though I think you specifically need a hurdle model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censored_regression_model